# Ubuntu 14.04 guest in Hyper-V host will not run apt-get

Tags: 14.04, hyper-v

I have a problem running apt-get (or any other command that requires a download) on Ubuntu 14.04 guest running in Hyper-V (W28K) server. The download always fails because the connection times out. It is not a problem with the ubuntu archives as I have tried several and also get the same problem with all other third party archives. However, the internet connection from the Ubuntu server works fine as I can ping from it successfully and connect into it from outside with SSH or to the Web server it is running. The guest Linux machine has a static IP and uses the external Hyper-V connection that I have set up for all other guest OSs running on the host. It seems that the Linux guest can make outgoing icmp connections to the Internet (which is why I get correct ping results) but cannot receive communications to complete the connection. Without apt-get working I cannot do anything with this guest server.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but my guess would be that you're not getting DNS resolution.  When you're pinging out, are you pinging an IP address or an FQDN?

If you're using a static IP, you need to add the dns-nameservers to the interfaces file

example:

`auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.0.150
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.0.1
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`